# Google Play still giving me zero devices

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to upload an update of my application in the Google Play store but I couldn't get more than 0 devices. I've tried to delete the permissions and still no luck. This is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.compan.st"
android:versionCode="9"
android:versionName="@string/app_verion" >

<!-- PERMISSIONS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:name="com.compan.st.app.ApplicationExt"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/MainMenuStrings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AcademicRecordActivity"
        android:label="@string/ACrecord"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SemesterActivity"
        android:label="@string/Semester"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.AcademicRecordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AboutUserActivity"
        android:label="@string/Aboutuser"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.RewardsActivity"
        android:label="@string/Rewards"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoansActiviry"
        android:label="@string/Loans"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.RequestsActivity"
        android:label="@string/Requests"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Preferences"
        android:label="@string/setting"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/about"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.Preferences"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.compan.st.activity.IntentReceiver" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.phone.ScheduleActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IOSched" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.CourseInfoActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ASchedule"
        android:label="@string/schedule" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

The previous version was compatible with most of devices "it was working with api 8".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem fixed. it turns out one of the JARs that are Java project I'm using in my Android project has libraries inside a folder called `lib` so I just move it to a new folder called `libs` then export the JAR, put it in my Android project then export the APK.